# tidyverse: replacing special characters in string

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I want to replace `_` with `\_` in a string.

```
Test <- 
  c(".model", "sigma2", "log_lik", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "ar_roots", 
"ma_roots")

library(stringr)

Test %>% 
  str_replace_all(string = ., pattern = "_", replacement = "\_")

Error: '\_' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\_"
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -

```
stringr::str_replace_all(Test, pattern = "_", replacement = "\\\\_")

#[1] ".model"     "sigma2"     "log\\_lik"  "AIC"     "AICc"       "BIC"       
#[7] "ar\\_roots" "ma\\_roots"
```

While printing `\` is escaped with another `\` so you see two backslash. To see actual string use `cat`

```
cat(stringr::str_replace_all(Test, pattern = "_", replacement = "\\\\_"))

#.model sigma2 log\_lik AIC AICc BIC ar\_roots ma\_roots
```

Or with `gsub` -

```
gsub("_", "\\\\_", Test)
```